# C# How do I create a collection of people, then print them out sorted in a certain way?

Tags: c#, list, collections

This is my first question on this site, and I'm really stuck with a problem in C# ;

I'm trying to create a list containing x amount of people based on user input.
When the list has been generated, I need to print them out sorted based on articles sold.

Here is my problem though;
After this has been done, I also need to connect people to certain levels (Like one level is >50 articles sold, one level 51-100 articles sold etc.)

The output should look something like this:

Name     District    Articles sold

Rich     New york    199

1 Seller has reached level 3: 100-199 articles

Mickey   Alabama     202

Snoopy   Texas       212

2 sellers have reached level 4: More than 199 articles

How would one go forward with this? Is the list solution in my current code a good way or not?

This is my current code:

```
public class newPerson
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string district { get; set; }
    public string articlesSold { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many people do you want to add to your collection?");
        int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        List<newPerson> personList = new List<newPerson>();

        for (int index = 0; index < answer; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write person {0}:s name:", index + 1);
            personList.Add(new newPerson()
            {
                name = Console.ReadLine(),
                district = Console.ReadLine(),
                articlesSold= Console.ReadLine(),
            });
        }

        var sortedPersonList = personList.OrderByDescending(p => p.articlesSold);

        Console.WriteLine("Name     |     District    |     Amount    |     ");
        foreach (var p in sortedPersonList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.Write((p.name) + "    |     ");
            Console.Write((p.district) + "    |     ");
            Console.Write((p.articlesSold + "    |     "));
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking about making a dictionary first instead of lists, but not sure which way to go.
If anything is unclear, I apologize. I'm very new to programming.

Comment: FYI, class names and public properties are typically PascalCase in c#

Comment: Also, `51-100` is a subset of `>50`. Did you mean `<50`?

Comment: Thank you for noting that, and yes <50!

Comment: `articlesSold` should be an `int` rather than a `string`, since it represents a number. (also, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60936703/edit) your question to make corrections rather than using the comments!)

Comment: You're right, I changed articlesSold to an int.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception if a valid integer is not input. Try using `int.TryParse` instead, so you can notify the user of invalid input and let them try again.

Comment: You should look into C#'s SortedList<TKey,TValue> class. It makes things a bit easier

Comment: With your `ArticlesSold` now being an int you can simply divide the value (cast as double) by 50 (double) and use `Floor` or `Ceiling` on the result. you might have to remove 1 from your value if you want to floor as your range is not 50 to 99 but 51 to 100

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it's helping a lot. Just wondering though; how do I print out each person in the list under the respective level based on the articles sold?

Answer (score 1):

@Raizee, a general approach to this would be the following:

1. Add a `Level` property to each `Person` object which computes that person's level from how many articles they've sold.
2. After you've generated your `List<Person>` group the people together by their level.
3. For each level, if there's a group which exists for that level then sort that group in ascending order on the number of articles sold and output the results.

An example implementation of the above three steps would be as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflowSandbox.ConsoleApp
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string District { get; set; }
        public int ArticlesSold { get; set; }

        public int Level
        {
            get
            {
                if (ArticlesSold > 199) // 200 and above
                    return 4;
                if (ArticlesSold > 99)  // [100,199]
                    return 3;
                if (ArticlesSold > 49)  // [50,99]
                    return 2;
                return 1;   // 49 and below
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var people = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() { Name = "Bob", District = "London", ArticlesSold = 500 },
                new Person() { Name = "Alice", District = "Detroit", ArticlesSold = 125 },
                new Person() { Name = "Jane", District = "New York", ArticlesSold = 150 },
                new Person() { Name = "Alex", District = "5", ArticlesSold = 500 }
            };

            var peopleGroupedByLevel = people
                .GroupBy(p => p.Level)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
            Console.WriteLine("Name | District | Amount");
            if (peopleGroupedByLevel.ContainsKey(1))
            {
                var levelOnePeople = peopleGroupedByLevel[1];
                Console.WriteLine($"{levelOnePeople.Count} Seller has reached level 1: less than 50 articles");
                var levelOnePeopleSortedByArticlesSold = levelOnePeople.OrderBy(p => p.ArticlesSold);
                PrintPeopleToConsole(levelOnePeopleSortedByArticlesSold);
            }
            if (peopleGroupedByLevel.ContainsKey(2))
            {
                var levelTwoPeople = peopleGroupedByLevel[2];
                Console.WriteLine($"{levelTwoPeople.Count} Seller has reached level 2: 50-99 articles");
                var levelTwoPeopleSortedByArticlesSold = levelTwoPeople.OrderBy(p => p.ArticlesSold);
                PrintPeopleToConsole(levelTwoPeopleSortedByArticlesSold);
            }
            if (peopleGroupedByLevel.ContainsKey(3))
            {
                var levelThreePeople = peopleGroupedByLevel[3];
                Console.WriteLine($"{levelThreePeople.Count} Seller has reached level 3: 100-199 articles");
                var levelTwoPeopleSortedByArticlesSold = levelThreePeople.OrderBy(p => p.ArticlesSold);
                PrintPeopleToConsole(levelTwoPeopleSortedByArticlesSold);
            }
            if (peopleGroupedByLevel.ContainsKey(4))
            {
                var levelFourPeople = peopleGroupedByLevel[4];
                Console.WriteLine($"{levelFourPeople.Count} Seller has reached level 4: More than 199 articles");
                var levelFourPeopleSortedByArticlesSold = levelFourPeople.OrderBy(p => p.ArticlesSold);
                PrintPeopleToConsole(levelFourPeopleSortedByArticlesSold);
            }
        }

        private static void PrintPeopleToConsole(IEnumerable<Person> people)
        {
            foreach (var person in people)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name} | {person.District} | {person.ArticlesSold}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in this example I hard-coded the input `List<Person>` because I didn't want to have to mess around repeatedly inputting the people.

Comment: This is amazing, I really appreciate the time you took for this. This did lots for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten a little bit:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public int ArticlesSold { get; set; }

    public int Level
    {
        get
        {
            if (ArticlesSold <= 50) return 1;
            if (ArticlesSold > 50 && ArticlesSold <= 100) return 2;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many people do you want to add to your collection?");
        var count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        var personList = new List<Person>();

        for (var index = 1; index <= count; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write person {0}:s name:", index + 1);
            personList.Add(new Person()
            {
                Name = Console.ReadLine(),
                District = Console.ReadLine(),
                ArticlesSold = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()),
            });
        }

        var sortedPersonList = personList.OrderByDescending(p => p.ArticlesSold);

        Console.WriteLine("Name     |     District    |     Amount    |    Level | ");
        foreach (var p in sortedPersonList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.Write((p.Name) + "    |     ");
            Console.Write((p.District) + "    |     ");
            Console.Write((p.ArticlesSold + "    |     "));
            Console.Write((p.Level + "    |     "));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Answer (score -1):

You could have a method in your newPerson class called CalculateLevel. This returns the level after you call it in your Console.Write. For example:

```
public int CalculateLevel()
{
   if (articlesSold <= 50) return 1;
}
```

Then in your print method you can call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Level: {p.CalculateLevel()}")
```

Comment: You cannot use the `<=` operator with a string and an integer...

Comment: Changed articlesSold to an int. Trying this solution gives me this error: 'newPerson.Calculatelevel()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: You'd need to add other `else if` statements, with a final `else` (or just add a `return` statement at the end of the method), so that all possible inputs return a value.